# Mysql union, get 2 information

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables

Table 1:

```
T1ID, Info
1,A
2,B
3,C
```

Table 2

```
T2ID, Info
1,D
2,E
3,F
```

Now I want a union of these with the following result

```
T1ID,T2ID,Info
1,null,A
2,null,B
3,null,C
null,1,D
null,2,E
null,3,F
```

Thank you

Comment: Add NULL to the select lists, in pos 2 resp pos 1.

Answer (score 2):

```
  select T1ID, null as T2ID, Info from T1
  union all
  select null as T1ID, T2ID, Info from T2
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
select T1ID,null,Info from table1
Union
select null,T2ID,Info from table2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it that way by simulating a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, to avoid specifying the `null` in the query :

```
SELECT T1ID, T2ID, T1.INFO AS INFO
FROM TABLE1 T1 LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.INFO=T2.INFO
UNION ALL
SELECT T1ID, T2ID, T2.INFO AS INFO
FROM TABLE1 T1 RIGHT JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.INFO=T2.INFO
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90362/24/0)

With `FULL OUTER JOIN` support it would have been simpler :

```
SELECT T1ID, T2ID, COALESCE(T1.INFO, T2.INFO) AS INFO
FROM TABLE1 T1 FULL OUTER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.INFO=T2.INFO
```